# Re-styling the new->item dropdown menu in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint

Is this even possible? I have many content types and instead of having to scroll down a massive list I'd like to re-style the control so that all my content types are listed in a wider multi column layout. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The possible way to do this is to create your own custom action which implements styling and then hide standard action. You can provide custom action with ControlSrc attribute and create any ascx control to style your action.
Please refer to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh500259%28v=office.14%29.aspx) post for further details.